# in exception_from_error_queue raise exception_type(errors) OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'not enough data')]

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-php-client

when I execute the below code i am getting following exception
raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'not enough data')]

when this line of code executed i am getting the exception.

```
     creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(filename, SCOPES)
```

how to correct this error please advice

```
 import pandas as pd
 from oauth2client.service_account  import ServiceAccountCredentials
 from googleapiclient.discovery import build

 filename = 'credentials.json'
 SCOPES ='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
 SPREADSHEET_ID = 'Xg6qs4D17I53Fgdm_irzDaH8z8LsyNZFPOT8B1Tt1Cw'
 DATA_TO_PULL = 'Instances'

 creds = None

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(filename, SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

if not values:
   print('No data found.')
else:
 rows = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                           range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()
 data = rows.get('values')
 print("COMPLETE: Data copied")
```